# Combine two rxjs streams and emit only if the first one it's true

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators, ngrx

I will need some help with a use case I'm stuck right now:

I'm implementing an autosaving feature in Angular 6 and Ngrx for a dialog 'form' (this case doesn't use  but it changes the state with some actions when clicking) with the following conditions:

- If any element is changed (selected), it triggers the timer of 30s, the user can change as many as he wants during that time and when the timer finish, emit the state. (If I change multiple inputs between those 30s, there will be only one emit)
- If the dialog is closed before the 30secs and data were changed on the form, it must be saved right away.

Currently, for the first case I have this observable:

```
this.configuration$ = this.store.pipe(select(getTopicsList));
this.configuration$
    .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(30000),
    skip(1),
).subscribe(res => this.saveCurrent());
```

Note: the `skip(1)` is only to skip the first emit when the component is being initialized

For the second I have and Subject converted to an Observable to emit an event every time the dialog is closed:

```
this.close$ = this.closeStream.asObservable();
```

With Observable operators, there is any way to combine both and condition the emit if changes in the `this.configuration$`observable had been made?

I'm not that strong in observables but maybe I'm overthinking and there is an efficient solution. It will be awesome in someone can give me a head with it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What about [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)? It only emits if both observable emit something, which wouldn't be the case if there are no changes in the first one. Or maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, I started with it but combineLatest will only emit if both observable have emitted at least one time, and I have to make sure that is the form has changed, a debounce of 30s is triggered but if I close AND they were some changes, it must emit right away.

Comment: try to use filter and check with your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`race`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html) but only after the form has changed.

Basically, every time the form changes, you want to save it either after a certain delay or once the user closes the modal, whatever comes first.

Like this, if instead of saving the form when the modal is closed you want to add a <kbd>Save</kbd> button, it would only be saved once until it changes again.

It should be something like this:

```js
const {
  Subject,
  of,
  race
} = rxjs;

const {
  distinctUntilChanged,
  skip,
  switchMap,
  delay,
  take
} = rxjs.operators;

let field = 0;

const formSubject = new Subject();
const closeSubject = new Subject();
const formObservable = formSubject.asObservable();
const closeObservable = closeSubject.asObservable();

document.getElementById('change').onclick = () => {
  console.clear();
  
  formSubject.next({ field: ++field });
};

document.getElementById('close').onclick = () => {
  console.clear();
  
  closeSubject.next(true);
};

formObservable.pipe(
  skip(1),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((form) => race(
    of(form).pipe(delay(2000)),
    closeObservable.pipe(take(1)).pipe(switchMap(() => of(form)))
  ))
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});

formSubject.next({ field });
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="change" onclick="change()">CHANGE</button>
  <button id="close" onclick="close()">CLOSE</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `race`. for example `race(observableOne$, observableTwo$)` will only emit the value of the first Observable to emit a value.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html

Comment: Hi, yes I tried also and was looking fine until I close the dialog without making any change and the observable emitted (It shouldn't emit if there is no change in the state)

Comment: @alvarosaburido, "filter" operator can solve this issue. No any change => no emission. Am I right?

Comment: In that case, you may want to try the distinct operator. it will not emit duplicate values. and oberservable of a---a---b---c will emit a---b---c with a distinct operator.